# Splitting data randomly in R

Tags: r, split

I have a data in .csv with 19020 observations. I need to split the data randomly into parts of 13020, 3000 and 3000 in R. I have tried the following code but it doesn't help me after the first step.

```
indexes = sample(1:nrow(HW2), size=13020)
indexes1 = sample(13020:nrow(HW2), size=16020)
```

Line2 is throwing me an error though.

Answer (score 5):

Can you use something like

```
index <- sample(19020)
part1 <- HW2[index[1:13020],]
part2 <- HW2[index[13021:16020],]
part3 <- HW2[index[16021:19020],]
```

Edited first line according to Pierre's suggestion

Comment: Could you accept the answer then? Keeps others from spending time on it when your issue is already solved.